# jgit - Delete .git directory (or get files without it)

Tags: java, git, jgit

I need to clone a git repo in java. I am using jGit.

The line of code I am using is :

```
Git clone = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(URIofRepo).setDirectory(localPath).call();
```

Where URIofRepo is : the github link to my repo
and
Where localPath is : the directory I want the clone to happen.

This works perfectly. However, since the use of the project I am doing doesn't require a clone for continued work, I simply want the clone to have the contents of the github repo WITHOUT the .git directory.

I tried also using the following :

```
    File dirToDelete = new File (path   + "/.git");
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dirToDelete);
```

However I got an IO exception saying I am unable to delete the file as follows :

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file:
>   C:\testing\testRepo1.git\objects\pack\pack-7ca7f11688adda065d62f3394d0e055346beff22.pack

Comment: You can always maintain a bare, mirror copy (that will allow not to clone each time) and use jgit's equivalent of `git archive`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that the current eclipse process keep an handle on the pack file, preventing its deletion.
As [Rüdiger Herrmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986905/r%C3%BCdiger-herrmann) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224283/jgit-delete-git-directory-or-get-files-without-it/27224365?noredirect=1#comment42928033_27224365):

> If the open file handle is what prevents the file from being deleted, make sure to close the repository that is returned by `init`:

```
clone.getRepository().close()
```

Another approach would be to download an archive of the GitHub repo  through [its archive link](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link).

Or using JGit to create an archive from your current local repo (see [`ArchiveTest.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/fd58cbcdee632100f239423194be9aaa951f7835/org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/pgm/ArchiveTest.java)), and unzip that archive for you to use.

Comment: If the open file handle is what prevents the file from being deleted, make sure to close the repository that is returned by init: `clone.getRepository().close()`.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 5):

This issue of unable to delete local repository still persisted even after trying following:

```
clone.getRepository().close()
```

I could fix the issue and successfully delete local repository after setting "options" value to RECURSIVE delete while calling delete() as follows:

```
 FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dirToDelete, 1);
```

This is what delete() document says:

> public static void delete(File f, int options) throws IOException
>   Delete file or folder
>
> Parameters: f - File to be deleted
>
> options - deletion options, RECURSIVE for recursive deletion of a subtree, RETRY to retry when deletion failed. Retrying may help if the underlying file system doesn't allow deletion of files being read by another thread.

Comment: Yes, the second way solved my problem. 

`FileUtils` should be imported from this library: 
`import org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtils;`

Not from this: 
`import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;`

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not your .close() will have an effect depends on how the repository was created. So even though you are calling close on a Git instance, it may or may not release the resources. I wasted so much of my time before I realized this.

***From Jgit documentation :***

If the repository was opened by a **static factory method in this class, then this method calls Repository.close()** on the underlying repository instance. (Whether this actually releases underlying resources, such as file handles, may vary; see Repository for more details.)

If the repository was created by a caller and passed into Git(Repository) or a static factory method in this class, **then this method does not call close on the underlying repository.**

Comment: Any Idea how we can overcome this?